# Create infinite list with Cloud Firestore in flutter

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am currently using Cloud Firestore with the Streambuilder widget in order to populate a ListView widget with Firestore documents.

```
new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('videos').limit(10).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Center(
      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
    return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        new Card(child: ...)
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

This setup however only allows for the querying of the first x results (in this case x=10), with x being a fixed number that will sooner or later be exceeded by the number of Card widgets the user wants to see as he or she scrolls down.

Would it now be possible to query the first x results, and after the user hits a scroll threshold to query the next x+10 results from Cloud Firestore and so on? 

 This would allow for a dynamic list length which would also benefit the Firestore data consumption.

Comment: That's definitely possible, but there's nothing pre-built in the API. You'll have to remember the last document on the first page, and then `startAfter()` with that document to get the second page of documents.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is possible or not with Streambuilder. I have integrated the similar functionality in my App using the `startAfter` method as shown below

```
class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  Feed({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  _FeedState createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  ScrollController controller;
  DocumentSnapshot _lastVisible;
  bool _isLoading;
  CollectionReference get homeFeeds => widget.firestore.collection('homefeed');
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _data = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _getData();
  }

  Future<Null> _getData() async {
//    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5));
    QuerySnapshot data;
    if (_lastVisible == null)
      data = await widget.firestore
          .collection('homefeed')
          .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
          .limit(3)
          .getDocuments();
    else
      data = await widget.firestore
          .collection('homefeed')
          .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
          .startAfter([_lastVisible['created_at']])
          .limit(3)
          .getDocuments();

    if (data != null && data.documents.length > 0) {
      _lastVisible = data.documents[data.documents.length - 1];
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          _data.addAll(data.documents);
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('No more posts!'),
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
          child: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: _data.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          if (index < _data.length) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = _data[index];
            return new Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: new Text(document['question']),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: new Opacity(
              opacity: _isLoading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child: new SizedBox(
                  width: 32.0,
                  height: 32.0,
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
        onRefresh: ()async{
            _data.clear();
            _lastVisible=null;
            await _getData();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (!_isLoading) {
      if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() => _isLoading = true);
        _getData();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This code is very interesting, and require a hell of explanation,Important note what if you put the paging limit in the query less than the screen size, then scroll listener never get called and there is no way to load data, so either you load more than the user screen or the user will be only limited to the first page query, this needs to be fixed, why the scrolllistener never get called if the user swipe it out of bound ?

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely possible, but there's nothing pre-built in the API.

You'll have to remember the last document on the first page, and then `startAfter()` with that document to get the second page of documents.

See the documentation on [Paginating Data with Query Cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Would the scroll threshold have to be implemented with a scroll controller or what is the most commonly used solution for an infinite list?

Comment: A paging adapter was just added to FirebaseUI. For inspiration I'd recommend looking at that: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter

Comment: This is for flutter @FrankvanPuffelen, you cannot try to answer with that. Flutter don't have all Java implementations this is the problem here. 
People must start really answering questions on stackoverflow and stop looking for those medals

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem as if you try to dynamically change the "limit" value dynamically, the stream goes into "connection.waiting" state for a brief moment and while that is happening, you won't be able to show any data.