# Flutter: Is there a cleaner way to infinite scroll off a Provider attribute?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

Problem: I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll that loads images. Using the provider pattern, V-VM-M architecture and listening to the metadata to build the listview leads to the listview 'blinking' as it's parent widget is rebuilt when the provider updates.

My hacky solution:

1. Firestore query that loads the data in blocks of 10 as a stream.
2. Provider model object that listens to the stream and writes to a list attribute.
3. Broadcast Stream Controller that emits the new size every time the size of the data changes.
4. View is listening to the stream of the size, and when it changes, builds a listview of Widgets with each having an index of the list of attributes in the provider model.
5. The widgets in the listview use the index and select on the provider to listen for updates, so they can get updates without rebuilding the listview.

This is how I have gotten around the V-VM-M architecture and firestore being a push that updates the model, while every infinite scroll solution I've seen are based on pulls that query the service directly. In this solution it scrolls to the end, doesn't scroll past, and scrolls smoothly without blinking.

The problem is it's really complicated and ugly. Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create infinite list with Cloud Firestore in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555077/create-infinite-list-with-cloud-firestore-in-flutter)

Comment: There is also [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14214369-infinite-scrolling-pagination-in-flutter) with plenty of information about how to do infinite scroller.